# How do I assign a comment to current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variable-assignment, instance-variables

I have this line in my `create` action

```
@comment = @video.comments.new(params[:comment])
```

A comment also belongs to the user who creates it. How can I assign it to the current_user? Where does it fit into this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @video.comments.new(params[:comment].merge({:user_id => current_user.id}))
```

I'm using [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000759)

Comment: nice, could I also append this to `@comment = @video.comments.find(params[:id])` in my `destroy` action?

Comment: You'd want to do:  `@video.comments.find(params[:id], :conditions => {:user_id => current_user.id})`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
@comment = @video.comments.new(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user
```